# Portable .reg file for 32- and 64- bit Windows?

Tags: windows, registry

We have a 32-bit Windows application that makes extensive use of the registry. Among other things, we store the User name / Institution and License keys in the registry. Some users seem to have problems entering that data into the installer; for them we have supplied a .reg file with the relevant info, however this causes problems under 64-bit Windows 7 (and others, I assume) in that the 32-bit app can't see the data. I was hoping to use the 32-bit version of regedit, however there doesn't seem to be a portable way of locating it inside a batch file. Does anyone have any suggestions? Failing a solution, I could write a 32-bit application that creates the keys and values: The OS should then place the data in the same place that the 32-bit app. will find them, but the .reg file would be preferable.

I've noticed that Windows 7 (64-bit) will store entries under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Wow6432Node. I've tried specifying this in a .reg file (using regedit), however the application couldn't find the key/values either (I tried storing keys under both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/ as well as in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Wow6432Node/ in an effort to be portable).

Answer (score 1):

Windows automatically redirect some registry keys for 32-bit applications in 64-bit versions of Windows [for having separate settings for 32 and 64 bits programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx) (similar to what happens with the `System32` and `SysWOW64` folders). For example a 32 bit application asking for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/App Name` will be redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/WOW6432Node/App Name` (that redirect is transparent to the application, from its point of view it's accessing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/App Name`).

Since you are using directly a `.reg` file and the Registry Editor is a 64-bit application in 64-bit Windows the redirect doesn't happen and those keys are written in the 64-bit part of the registry.

Also that is the reason your 32-bit program can't find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/WOW6432Node` because it would be redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/WOW6432Node/WOW6432Node`.

Both of your proposed solution should work:

- Using a 32-bit app for creating the keys will work because redirection would take place by default.
- Creating both keys should also work as the expense of having another "garbage" key, in 32-bit Windows the regular key will be used and in 64-bit Windows your app would be redirected to `WOW6432Node`. It shouldn't be a problem because `WOW6432Node` is unused in 32 bits versions of Windows (it don't event exists).